# Python, measuring sound from sund card

Tags: python, python-sounddevice

I have been working some hours now trying to figure out a way to measure sound volume from an application without having a microphone.

I first tried with PyAudio but all examples is with using a microphone as capturing device for the sound from the speakers, but as I do not own a microphone this becomes hard.

Then I found python-sounddevice and it seems like it should work, but I keep getting errors trying to fetch the sound.

Here is the code I use:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

duration = 10
print("___________")
print("Devices:\n" + str(sd.query_devices()))
sd.default.device = [1, 1]
sd.default.channels = [0, 2]
print("___________")


def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    print(int(volume_norm))


with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
    sd.sleep(duration * 1000)
```

I print the devices so I will print them here:

```
Devices:
  0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME (0 in, 2 out)
< 1 Högtalare (High Definition Audi, MME (0 in, 2 out)
  2 Primär ljuddrivrutin, Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
  3 Högtalare (High Definition Audio Device), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
  4 Högtalare (High Definition Audio Device), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
  5 SPDIF Out (HD Audio SPDIF out 2), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
  6 SPDIF Out (HD Audio SPDIF out), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
  7 Speakers (HD Audio Speaker), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 6 out)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound_handler.py", line 17, in <module>
    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
  File "C:\Users\breid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 1662, in __init__
    **_remove_self(locals()))
  File "C:\Users\breid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 780, in __init__
    'Error opening {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
  File "C:\Users\breid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 2572, in _check
    raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening Stream: Invalid number of channels [PaErrorCode -9998]
```

Maybe I am approching this the wrong way, The channels is 0 in 2 out and I tries that as default.

Comment: `0` is indeed an invalid number of channels. Since none of your devices seem to have any input channels, you cannot use `sd.Stream`, which requires at least 1 input and 1 output channel. BTW, the `sounddevice` module uses the same C library (namely "PortAudio") as PyAudio under the hood. So if it doesn't work in PyAudio, it's very likely not to work with the `sounddevice` module, either.

Comment: In windows one are supposed to be able to activate some stereomix that should render an input device. I have not had time to try this out, maybe in the weekend.

Comment: If you happen to mean "WASAPI loopback", this will not work with the official PortAudio release (see https://lists.columbia.edu/pipermail/portaudio/2018-December/001674.html and https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries/issues/6). If you manage to compile it, you can use this unofficial version: https://github.com/audacity/audacity/tree/master/lib-src/portaudio-v19.